# How to replace values of a column with its WOE values in 1 shot in R

Tags: r

I am working on a credit card prospect identification case study. I have to replace values of all columns with its corresponding WOE values. I can do it in 2-3 steps. However, I want to know whether there is a way to do it in 1 shot.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expecfed output along with 2-3 steps code you tried.  We don't know what `WOE` values.

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to use acronyms without explaining what they stand for. And yes, as it has already been said, questions without any code are much less likely to be answered.

Comment: I would suggest showing your data structure and how you are doing it now. Otherwise there is a lot of assumptions that need to be made. For example: what do you mean by all columns ? don't you need to replace only one column ? do you already have the weight of evidence values ? do you need to rebin your variables ? (there is a guideline/help  of stack on how to ask a well formulated question...)

Comment: This is the link to the guideline that was just mentioned: [Click here.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scorecard package and it is simple to use `woebin(),woebin_plot(),woebin_ply(),iv()` function.

```
temp <- credit_data

library(scorecard)

bins <- woebin(dt = temp,y = "targetvariable")

woebin_plot(bins$Income)

WOE_temp <- woebin_ply(temp,bins)

View(WOE_temp)

View(temp[is.na(temp$No.of.dependents),])

IV_values <- iv(dt = temp,y = "target variable")
(IV_values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [woe package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/woe/woe.pdf) (in case WOE stands for Weight of Evidence).

Here's the relevant code snippet from the documentation:

```
library(woe)
res_woe <- woe(Data = mtcars, Independent = "cyl", Continuous = FALSE, Dependent = "am", C_Bin = 10, Bad = 0, Good = 1)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18862917)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please follow the following steps :-

**Step 1:** Calculate woe and iv using information package:-

library(fuzzyjoin)

library(Information)

```
IV <-
  Information::create_infotables(data = test_df,
                                 y = "label_column",
                                 parallel =
                                   TRUE)
```

Where in 'y' we need to assign label and 'data' we need to assign a dataframe.

**Step 2:** Use the following function:-
This is my own custom written function to replace actual values in a dataframe with woe calculated using information package:-

```
woe_replace <- function(df_orig, IV) {
  df <- cbind(df_orig)
  df_clmtyp <- data.frame(clmtyp = sapply(df, class))
  df_col_typ <-
    data.frame(clmnm = colnames(df), clmtyp = df_clmtyp$clmtyp)
  for (rownm in 1:nrow(df_col_typ)) {
    colmn_nm <- toString(df_col_typ[rownm, "clmnm"])    
    if(colmn_nm %in% names(IV$Tables)){
    column_woe_df <- cbind(data.frame(IV$Tables[[toString(df_col_typ[rownm, "clmnm"])]]))
    if (df_col_typ[rownm, "clmtyp"] == "factor" | df_col_typ[rownm, "clmtyp"] == "character") {
      df <-
        dplyr::inner_join(
          df,
          column_woe_df[,c(colmn_nm,"WOE")],
          by = colmn_nm,
          type = "inner",
          match = "all"
        )
      df[colmn_nm]<-NULL
      colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="WOE"]<-colmn_nm
    } else if (df_col_typ[rownm, "clmtyp"] == "numeric" | df_col_typ[rownm, "clmtyp"] == "integer") {
      column_woe_df$lv<-as.numeric(str_sub(
        column_woe_df[,colmn_nm],
        regexpr("\\[", column_woe_df[,colmn_nm]) + 1,
        regexpr(",", column_woe_df[,colmn_nm]) - 1
      ))
      column_woe_df$uv<-as.numeric(str_sub(
        column_woe_df[,colmn_nm],
        regexpr(",", column_woe_df[,colmn_nm]) + 1,
        regexpr("\\]", column_woe_df[,colmn_nm]) - 1
      ))
      column_woe_df[colmn_nm]<-NULL      
      column_woe_df<-column_woe_df[,c("lv","uv","WOE")]      
      colnames(df)[colnames(df)==colmn_nm]<-"WOE_temp2381111111111111697"      
      df <-
        fuzzy_inner_join(
          df,
          column_woe_df[,c("lv","uv","WOE")],
          by = c("WOE_temp2381111111111111697"="lv","WOE_temp2381111111111111697"="uv"),
          match_fun=list(`>=`,`<=`) 
        )      
      df["WOE_temp2381111111111111697"]<-NULL      
      df["lv"]<-NULL      
      df["uv"]<-NULL      
      colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="WOE"]<-colmn_nm      
    }}
  }
  return(df)
}
```

**Function Call:-**

```
test_df_woe <- woe_replace(test_df, IV)
```

**OR Super one Shot:-**

```
test_df_woe <- woe_replace(test_df,Information::create_infotables(data = test_df, y = "label_column",parallel =TRUE))
```